# Cannot find library when building with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt-creator

I'm using ubuntu  12.04 64-bit.

I when building a project I receive an error:

> cannot find -lNSPR
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

the .pro file contains

> ```
> libraries.path = /opt/my_dir
> libraries.files = \
>     engine/x64/libNSPR.so \
> ```

Why can't it find the library?

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround so far - I just put libNSPR.so into /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory.

From there linker picked the library and build was successful.

I understand that it's not the best way to solve the problem, so constuctive criticism is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Install Qt libraries by apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-core libqt4-gui
```

Also you can install for having all libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-*
```

Comment: thak's, but that didn't help.

Comment: Check your include directories to see if they contain any such filename, and either add it to your INCLUDES project file variable, or modify your QMAKESPEC *.conf file to use the correct path to Qt.